# Modulus with big numbers in java

Tags: java, integer, bigdecimal, modulus, algebra

I'm programming an RSA decryption prototype in java. It's just for showing how it works for school which is why I try to keep it as simple as possible. But when I get to the decryption part I have to use the formula:

**c = m^e % n.**

For testing purposes I tried to do that with **m = "1010"** (because I get it as a String from my program), **e = 55**, **n = 361**. This should give me 345 as c(tested in windows calculator). The results I'm getting are:

```
Math.pow(Integer.parseInt("1010"), 55) % 361 // 115.0

BigDecimal b = BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(Integer.parseInt("1010"),55));

(b.remainder(BigDecimal.valueOf(361))).doubleValue() // 300.0

Math.pow(Integer.parseInt("1010"), 55) % 361 //  340
```

Please tell me where I am wrong or how I can fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Math.pow(1010, 55)` will be quite a few bits off, so the mod value is probably way off too. But try `BigInteger.valueOf(1010).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(55), BigInteger.valueOf(361))`. I have no idea why you are using **BigDecimal instead of BigInteger** for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to use `BigInteger`, in this case, it will be useful knowing that the exponentiations may result ( at most of the times) an overflow. Here I came with an application of your example using `BigInteger`, I hope it will help :

```
 BigInteger m  = BigInteger.valueOf(1010);
 BigInteger e  = BigInteger.valueOf(55);
 BigInteger n  = BigInteger.valueOf(361);
 BigInteger c = m.modPow(e,n);
 System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: I strongly suggest using BigDecimal here.

Comment: @MS90 would you explain the reasons why you suggest using `BigDecimal ` ?

Comment: @MS90: **BigDecimal is a terribly wrong choice for this**. This deals with integers only, and the result is integral too. BigInteger is more performant and better suited for this.

Comment: For instance because of sentinel properties assuming he deals with cryptography case ( in all other cases, I would prefer BigInteger too for mod-power operation).

Comment: Thanks this does the trick for me. I changed to BigDecimal during experimenting phase, of course BigInteger makes more sense. I guess the real problem was that I wasn't using .modPow().